# IOS - Only work on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code:

First view controller

```
- (IBAction)finishedCreated:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{
    CreateWifiCacheViewController *vc = unwindSegue.sourceViewController;
    self.l_nameCache.text = vc.info;
    NSLog(@"%@", @"WORKING!!!!");
}
```

Second view controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@", @"Trying to unwind");
    self.info = self.tf_test.text;
}
```

That code is connected to a button, but only work in the simulator. When i run on a real device, simply doesn't work. The methods are not called, or don't run. Not even show an error, on device, or at Xcode! 
The project target IOS is minimum 7.0, and my device has 7.1.2.

Comment: are u saying that button click isn't working on device ?

Comment: No. The button is created, but when i click, nothing happens in the real device. On the simulator it unwind. The effect click on the device work!

Comment: Are you sure you added the UIControlEventTouchUpInside action to the button and not some other action?

Comment: If not why work on simulator? @BogdanBalta